# Non smooth faces in shade smooth

Tags: mesh, shaders, edges, faces

I ran into a problem that when I turn on shadow smooth, it desnt't work on all faces. Please help me understand how to fix this.

[image]

As you can see, it also doesn't depend on the angle:

[image]

[image]

Comment: May be some normals are flipped, check it with backface culling and/or try to recalculate normals.

Comment: Could you upload a file?